# window.open is not opening a new window when used with parameters

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

**On clicking of the HyperLink , i am calling the below function**

```
window.open("<%=forHyperLink%>",'name','height=600,width=800');
```

**The issue is that , with the above line , only one time Hyper Link click is working 
(That is if another hyper link is clicked , no window is being opened up)**

But if i remove the parameters for window.open and simply use

```
window.open("<%=forHyperLink%>");
```

Then on click of every Hyperlink a new window is being opened.

Please adivce .

Comment: Please show HOW you call this code. If you have `onclick="window.open("` then the quotes are wrong. If you reuse the "name" which is not a good name for a window, it may go behind. try '_blank' instead

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change the `name` of each window per link so the window opened on initial click won't be re-used.

I'm guessing that clicking on other links opens the links on the initial/currently opened pop-up and causes confusion that it doesn't open new windows.

```
// first window to open
window.open("first.html",'name','height=600,width=800');

// opens in the same window where first.html is opened because 
// it targets the same window called `name`
window.open("second.html",'name','height=600,width=800');

// this works because by default it will open a new one everytime it is executed
window.open("new.html");

// opens a window with unique name 
window.open("<%=forHyperLink%>",'name_' + Math.random(),'height=600,width=800');
```

Comment: Than you for your suggestions , i want to open the sam epage by clicking on the hyper links , how can i chnage the name of the HTML Page ??

Comment: you could add some random numbers to change the window name and make it unique for each e.g. `window.open("<%=forHyperLink%>",'name_' + Math.random(),'height=600,width=800');
` let me update my answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.open("<%=forHyperLink%>",'name_'+(new Date()).getTime(),'height=600,width=800');`

'name_'+(new Date()).getTime() will be changed at each window opened

oNewWindow = window.open( [sURL] [, sName] [, sFeatures] [, bReplace])

Please find the detail of window.open from the following link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536651(v=vs.85).aspx